# hide all checkboxes in table not working

Tags: jquery, loops, hide

my jquery loops through all tables

I would like to hide  all spans with the class="cbox" and all checkboxes within the current table
but my code isnt working.

```
     var table_ids = new Array();
    $('.sizetable')
   .each(function(e){
    tableid = $(this).attr('id');


    //$msg = tableid;
    //alert($msg); This alerts the correct id 
    $( "#" + tableid + " .cbox").hide();
    $( "#" + tableid + " input:checkbox").hide();

     };
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/tommyd/Br42j/

Comment: In your fiddle, nothing has the class sizetable

Comment: ...but .sizetable does not appear in your html, so $('.sizetable') returns an empty set.

Sorry - Robert caught me typing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$('.sizetable .cbox, .sizetable input:checkbox').hide()`. Selecting by ID is faster, but you're already selecting by class to get the ID, might as well just go from there and hide all `.cbox` and `input:checkbox`

Comment: I cant because I dont know how many and which tables will be printed to the page

Comment: That will select all of them.

Comment: The code I posted is a simplified version of the code i have. My original code needs to be run seporately on each table

Comment: Okay, well then use `$('input:checkbox', this)` and `$('.cbox', this)` within the `.each()`

Comment: Are you looking to make it do something more towards http://www.jsfiddle.net/yAgUx/20/ ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error, you are missing closing ')'. 
So change your code to:

```
var table_ids = new Array();
$('.sizetable').each(function(e){
    tableid = $(this).attr('id');
    //$msg = tableid;
    //alert($msg); This alerts the correct id 
    $( "#" + tableid + " .cbox").hide();
    $( "#" + tableid + " input:checkbox").hide();

});
```

Check the code below too(changed the selectors to make it little faster):

```
var table_ids = new Array();
$('.sizetable span.cbox, .sizetable input:checkbox').hide();
```

**EDIT**: Check this post at fiddle.net http://www.jsfiddle.net/Br42j/7/, I added the sizetable class to the table and added the missing ) 
And for optimized version check this:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/Br42j/8/

Comment: that worked on my simple version but why not on my original http://www.jsfiddle.net/tommyd/yAgUx/

Comment: Can you post it with HTML too?